Doubt in the proof of Thue's theorem in Schmidt's book
Theorem: Let $F(X, Y)=a_0 X^d+a_1 X^{d-1} Y+\cdots+a_d Y^d$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a form of degree $d \geqq 3$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z} $ be given. The equation
$$
F(x, y)=m
$$
has only finitely many integer solutions $(x, y)$.
Proof: Factoring $F(x, y)$ over $\mathbb{C}$, we can write
$$
a_0 \left(x-\alpha_1 y\right) \cdots\left(x-\alpha_d y\right)= m
$$
Then dividing by $y^d$ and taking absolute values gives
$$
\left|a_0 \right|\left|\alpha_1-\frac{x}{y}\right| \cdots\left|\alpha_d-\frac{x}{y}\right|=\left|\frac{m}{y^d}\right|.
$$
We have, without loss of generality,
$$
\left|x-\alpha_1 y\right|=\min _{1 \leqq i \leqq d}\left|x-\alpha_i y\right|
$$
which is the same as
$$
\left|\alpha_1-\frac{x}{y}\right|=\min _{1 \leqq i \leqq d}\left|\alpha_i-\frac{x}{y}\right| .
$$
Also, let
$$
\gamma=\frac{1}{2} \min _{i \neq j}\left|\alpha_i-\alpha_j\right|>0
$$
If $y$ is large, then both sides of the second equation will be small. In particular, $\left|\alpha_1-\frac{x}{y}\right|$ will be small.
For $i \neq 1$, observe that
$$
\left|\alpha_i-\frac{x}{y}\right| \geqq\left|\alpha_i-\alpha_1\right|-\left|\alpha_1-\frac{x}{y}\right| \geqq 2 \gamma-\gamma=\gamma
$$

My doubt is the following:
I understand that the large value of $y$ makes the right-hand side of the second equation small. But I do not know how it makes any term on the left-hand side (in particular, $\left|\alpha_1-\frac{x}{y}\right|$) small. For example, if $\alpha_1 = 10$ and $y = 10^6,$ then $\left|\alpha_1-\frac{x}{y}\right|$ is still approximately $10.$
The step $ \left|\alpha_i-\frac{x}{y}\right| \geqq \gamma$follows only if  $\left|\alpha_1-\frac{x}{y}\right| < \gamma.$ But how can we guarantee this inequality is true?

Why do you think that $|\alpha_1 - x/y|$ is approximately $10$?  The value of $x$ could easily make it much smaller.

Okay. But how do we understand that the value of $x$ will indeed make it much smaller?

The idea is that as the right-hand shrinks, the value of $x$ is forced to make it smaller.

The hypothesis underlying the proof is that $F(x,y) = m$.  Of course that implies that $x/y$ will be close to a root of the corresponding polynomial, provided $y$ is large compared to $m$.  This will not happen for a random $x$; the hypothesis already makes $x$ quite special.

The last step comes from dividing the right-hand side $m/y^d$ by the lower bounds on $|\alpha_i - x/y|$ that work for all $i\ge 2$.  I'm not sure if you noticed that the order of the $\alpha_i$ was chosen so that $\alpha_1$ is the closest root to $x/y$ (technically, "a closest root" because there might be ties).
The lower bound in turn comes from the basic observation that there is a minimum spacing between the roots (which are distinct by irreducibility), and only one of them can be close to $x/y$ relative to $\gamma$.  Yes, technically the calculation as written assumes that $|\alpha_1 - x/y| \le \gamma$.  But even if $|\alpha_1 - x/y| > \gamma$, it's still true that $|\alpha_i - x/y| > \gamma$ because $\alpha_1$ is chosen to be closest.

Sorry, I rephrased my question. I was not precise with my doubt earlier.

I would say you are still not very precise with your doubt.  I already anticipated that issue and updated my answer,
